# To do list mini project

Tags: c#, beginner, console, to-do-list

I tried in this project to apply what I learned from OOP, using classes and properties, please advise for any best practice or any improvement.

Conclusion:
I have a text file "ToDoList.txt" which has the following syntax **Task,status** for example:
`Shopping,0
cooking,1
pick up kids from school,2
do something,0`

And I have two classes:

- **TaskData** class which only has properties and it will return the status in text(Completed or not completed)
- **FilterData** class which is going to filter the data according to the status

**Main Program class:**

```
namespace ExtractingDataFromTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Save Results of text data and declaring the text file to 
            //Read Data from.

            TaskData textData = new TaskData();

            string path = "ToDoList.txt";

            //Create a string to read all data in file
            string[] allData = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            //Assign each data to TextData object properties
            foreach (var task in allData)
            {
                PrintData(textData, task);
            }
            FilterData filterData = new FilterData();

            //Filter to show Completed Tasks only
            string[] completedTasks = filterData.ShowCompleted(allData);
            Console.WriteLine("\nFilter only completed tasks:");
            foreach (var task in completedTasks)
            {
                PrintData(textData, task);   
            }

            //Filter to show uncompleted Taks only
            string[] unCompletedTasks = filterData.ShowUnCompleted(allData);
            Console.WriteLine("\nFilter only Un-completed tasks:");
            foreach (var task in unCompletedTasks)
            {
                PrintData(textData, task);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        //This method will print data to the console
        private static void PrintData(TaskData textData, string task)
        {
            string[] lineData = task.Split(',');
            textData.Name = lineData[0];
            textData.Status = lineData[1];
            Console.WriteLine($"Task: {textData.Name}, Status:[{textData.Status}]");
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskData class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExtractingDataFromTextFile
{
    class TaskData
    {
        private string _status;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status
        {
            get {return _status; }
            //The setter will convert status from number to text
            //0 --> Not completed
            //1 --> Completed
            set
            {
                if (value == "0")
                {
                    _status = "Not completed";
                }
                else if(value =="1")
                {
                    _status = "Completed";
                }
                else
                {
                    _status = "Unknown";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterData class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExtractingDataFromTextFile
{
    class FilterData
    {
        private List<string> _filterData = new List<string>();

        //This function will filter the list to show only completed tasks
        public string[] ShowCompleted(string[] allData)
        {
            _filterData = new List<string>(); //Recreate the list to delete old filter
            foreach (var line in allData)
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split(',');
                if (lineData[1] == "1")
                {
                    //Completed task
                    _filterData.Add($"{lineData[0]},{lineData[1]}");
                }
            }
            return _filterData.ToArray();
        }

        //This function will filter the list to show only un-completed tasks
        public string[] ShowUnCompleted(string[] allData)
        {
            _filterData = new List<string>(); //Recreate the list to deleted old filter
            foreach (var line in allData)
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split(',');
                if (lineData[1] == "0")
                {
                    //Un-Completed task
                    _filterData.Add($"{lineData[0]},{lineData[1]}");
                }
            }
            return _filterData.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 5 → 3.

Comment: @Mast Thank you, I followed the link and answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PrintData method you are assigning values to TaskData object but you don't seem to do anything with it besides just printing it out.

I would parse the file into a List at the beginning and then work with this collection in later code.

```
private static List<TaskData> ParseTaskData(string[] allData)
{
    var tasksData = new List<TaskData>();

    foreach (var task in allData)
    {
        string[] lineData = task.Split(',');

        tasksData.Add(new TaskData()
        {
            Name = lineData[0],
            // Before Enum: Status = lineData[1]
            Status = (Status)int.Parse(lineData[1].ToString())
        });
    };

    return tasksData;
}
```

Also your filter methods can then work as one-liners with lambda. I would be tempted here to split property Status into `Status` and `StatusReadable`. Make `Status` an Enum for ease of filtering.

```
public List<TaskData> ShowUnCompletedFromList(List<TaskData> allData)
{
    return allData.Where(w => w.Status == "Not completed").ToList();
}
```

Enum solution (I changed the `ParseTaskData` above):

```
internal enum Status
{
    NotCompleted = 0,
    Completed = 1
}
```

And TaskData then becomes:

```
internal class TaskData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public string StatusDescription
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == Status.NotCompleted)
            {
                return "Not completed";
            }
            else if (Status == Status.Completed)
            {
                return "Completed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Unknown";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Filtering is now based on Enum and not magic strings:

```
public List<TaskData> ShowUnCompletedFromList(List<TaskData> allData)
{
    // With Magic string: return allData.Where(w => w.Status == "Not completed").ToList();
    return allData.Where(w => w.Status == Status.NotCompleted).ToList();
}
```

Try it out with Enum solution:

```
// Parse all tasks to List.
var tasksData = ParseTaskData(allData);

// Show items in List<>.
Console.WriteLine(">> All tasks:");

foreach (var task in tasksData)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task: {task.Name} is {task.StatusDescription}.");
}

Console.WriteLine(">> Uncompleted tasks:");
foreach (var uncompletedTask in filterData.ShowUnCompletedFromList(tasksData))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task: {uncompletedTask.Name} is {uncompletedTask.StatusDescription}.");
}

// Actually no need for a filter method, this one-liner does it the same as above.
Console.WriteLine(">> Uncompleted tasks short:");
filterData.ShowUnCompletedFromList(tasksData).ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($"Task: {e.Name} is {e.StatusDescription}."));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reviewing, can your explain more about **Make Status an Enum for ease of filtering** how enum is easier to filter.

Comment: Also is it a good practice to make a method to print the filtered data from **FilterData** class instead of the Program Class? as following code `public void PrintCompleted(string[] FilteredData)
{
// code to print
}`
This code will be called in Main method as such
`filterData.PrintCompleted(filterData.ShowCompleted(allData));`

Comment: @AMJ I'm on my phone, I'll get back to you regarding first comment when I get to a PC. Regarding your second comment - yes, if you would need to print the data often or perhaps 'prettify' it etc. then go for a separate method. The `Main` method will be cleaner and you would promote code reusage (DRY).

Comment: @AMJ I changed to code to implement an Enum. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, using enum really was a game changer made the code easier to understand! Also I used Task.Name instead of Task[0] which look better as well. Is it possible to post my reviewed code here ? i dont know if the rules allows that.

Comment: @AMJ I'm not sure about the rules for posting modified code. If you keep the original question as-is and edit your solution below that, it would probably be ok.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my solution, didnt use the lambda expression though because i didnt understand how to use it yet, I see the tutorials and documentations always explain delegates first then anonymous method which made me confuse, do you have any recommended reference?idk if u will be able to post here or send me  message. I will mark this thread as answered. EDIT: thanks a lot for the review it really helped me boost my confidence in using classes and objects.

Comment: @Iztoksson For future reference: no, it's not. Please take a look at [this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).